# How to use Jquery datepicker to select datetime from MqSql database to echo result on screen?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, datepicker

The code below shows the datepicker inputs to where I would just like to show from the database an echo on screen, of selected dates. Can anyone help with this please ?

JavaScript:

```
  <label for="from">From</label>
  <input type="text" name="from" id="from"/>
  <label for="to">To:</label>
  <input type="text" name="to" id="to"/>

   $( "#from" ).datepicker();
   $( "#to" ).datepicker();
   $( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", {dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yyT00:00:00', showAnim: 'show' });
   $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", {dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yyT23:59:59',showAnim: 'show'});

    $('#to').val(to);
    $('#from').val(from);
```

PHP:
The datepicker then sends to the URL to which fetches the results, but its not working.

```
var from = getParameterByName('from'); 
var to = getParameterByName('to');

var from = parseDateTime($('#from').val()); 
var to = parseDateTime($('#to').val()); 

my.php?=from='+from+'&to='+to+'&rand='+Math.random()

$query = 'SELECT * FROM register WHERE time BETWEEN ( "#from" ) AND ( "#to" )';
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo $row['time']."<br>";
}
```

Comment: I've read and reread this and have no clue what you're asking? can you rephrase the question as your code makes no sense as you're changing `#from` and `#to` 3 times for no reason which is obvious to me

Comment: What how to fetch from database a from and to date, you mean?

Comment: Ok, I'd use something like `ajax` for this, or, you could pass the details on the URL to the code with the PHP in

Comment: Yes your right Iv now added, what I should of to begin with. This just isnt working for me tho, any ideas what Im doing wrong?

Comment: Need to see all/more of your code - how are you setting the variables to go in the URL?

Comment: Please alter the question with more of your code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98913/discussion-between-jonas-and-darren-sweeney).

Comment: Unfortunately I'm at work so can't

Comment: Ok, no worries, do you think you maybe able to help?

Comment: If you can add more code to your question I can look when I can, sure

Comment: _The datepicker then sends to the URL to which fetches the results, but its not working._. What is not working exactly? What results do you get?

Comment: The URL is working as you can see it's trying to fetch the from and to, but im not getting any results, not even a echo. It's must be the URL not talking to Mysql datebase but not sure why it's not.